# What's the best QT Widget to use for 2D graphics?

Tags: c++, qt

My requirements are:

- display lots of 2D shapes (paths, transparency, lots of primitive shapes)
- fast (can update every millisecond if possible)
- zoom-able and pan-able, but I don't want scroll bars

Right now I'm extending QWidget directly and overriding `paintEvent`. I've also seen QGraphicsView, GLWindow, and some other ones floating around. Which one should I use? What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of shapes and navigation (zoom/pan) demands for the `QGraphicsView` approach, imho. It supports binary space partitioning to increase drawing speed.
Yet I don't know of what use it might be to redraw it once every millisecond.

Comment: I don't want to accept this answer because it only provides information on one possible option, but I will upvote to show my appreciation